# Как задать цвет кнопкам навигации через js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Работая с библиотекой Swiper.js столкнулся с проблемой, что нужно менять цвет при нажатии, но svg не меняет цвет

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7w18ypog/)

```js
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
    loop: true,
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
    autoplay: {
        delay: 15000,
    },
    pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        type: 'bullets',
    },
    simulateTouch: false,
});
const navColor = document.querySelector(".swiper-button-prev svg")
navColor.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.add("active");
  });
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500&display=swap');
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    background-color: #1F1F22;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
}
svg:hover {
    color: #D5A033;
}
.swiper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.swiper-text {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2222;
}
.swiper-text h1 {
    margin: 200px 0px 0px 175px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #D9B271;
    font-size: 48px;
    line-height: 58.51px;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.active {
    color: #D5A033;
}
.swiper-text p {
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 19.5px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 30px 0px 0px 175px;
}
.swiper-button-prev, .swiper-button-next {
    margin: 0px 80px;
}
.swiper-button-next::after, .swiper-button-prev::after {
    content: "";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <title>Slider</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="swiper">
        <div class="swiper-text">
            <h1>Тренажерный<br>зал</h1>
            <p>В нашем клубе есть все для кроссфита</p>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://psv4.userapi.com/c235031/u524861121/docs/d34/ffdee0a224ec/strong-man-training-gym_3_1.png?extra=Pe_bJb7ma7Vmw2NHVcAvWvKvd3uIV5BoBrNrW5IU3vM5oOR5CY2FdPoDBoewzVaDqt5fjtQNuyBbUfI8W75dT0jy3lZiTZOvlnd4Z_hwUWXwd1UUX2Oo26EE0vbacd-Ow-06_noaFaNDic4NF8nFUQk">
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://psv4.userapi.com/c235031/u524861121/docs/d34/ffdee0a224ec/strong-man-training-gym_3_1.png?extra=Pe_bJb7ma7Vmw2NHVcAvWvKvd3uIV5BoBrNrW5IU3vM5oOR5CY2FdPoDBoewzVaDqt5fjtQNuyBbUfI8W75dT0jy3lZiTZOvlnd4Z_hwUWXwd1UUX2Oo26EE0vbacd-Ow-06_noaFaNDic4NF8nFUQk">
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://psv4.userapi.com/c235031/u524861121/docs/d34/ffdee0a224ec/strong-man-training-gym_3_1.png?extra=Pe_bJb7ma7Vmw2NHVcAvWvKvd3uIV5BoBrNrW5IU3vM5oOR5CY2FdPoDBoewzVaDqt5fjtQNuyBbUfI8W75dT0jy3lZiTZOvlnd4Z_hwUWXwd1UUX2Oo26EE0vbacd-Ow-06_noaFaNDic4NF8nFUQk">
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://psv4.userapi.com/c235031/u524861121/docs/d34/ffdee0a224ec/strong-man-training-gym_3_1.png?extra=Pe_bJb7ma7Vmw2NHVcAvWvKvd3uIV5BoBrNrW5IU3vM5oOR5CY2FdPoDBoewzVaDqt5fjtQNuyBbUfI8W75dT0jy3lZiTZOvlnd4Z_hwUWXwd1UUX2Oo26EE0vbacd-Ow-06_noaFaNDic4NF8nFUQk">
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://psv4.userapi.com/c235031/u524861121/docs/d34/ffdee0a224ec/strong-man-training-gym_3_1.png?extra=Pe_bJb7ma7Vmw2NHVcAvWvKvd3uIV5BoBrNrW5IU3vM5oOR5CY2FdPoDBoewzVaDqt5fjtQNuyBbUfI8W75dT0jy3lZiTZOvlnd4Z_hwUWXwd1UUX2Oo26EE0vbacd-Ow-06_noaFaNDic4NF8nFUQk">
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev">
            <svg width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M15.3333 10.3467L9.66662 15.9973M9.66662 15.9973L15.3333 21.6478M9.66662 15.9973L22.6666 15.9973" stroke="white" stroke-width="2"/>
                <ellipse cx="16" cy="15.9971" rx="15" ry="14.9573" transform="rotate(-180 16 15.9971)" stroke="white" stroke-width="2"/>
            </svg>  
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-button-next">
            <svg width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M16.6666 21.6475L22.3333 15.997M22.3333 15.997L16.6666 10.3465M22.3333 15.997L9.33325 15.997" stroke="white" stroke-width="2"/>
                <ellipse cx="16" cy="15.9971" rx="15" ry="14.9573" stroke="white" stroke-width="2"/>
            </svg>  
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Если речь идет о ваших эллипсах, то по селекторам `.swiper-button-prev:active svg, .swiper-button-next:active svg {
  fill: red;
}`

Comment: .swiper-button-prev, .swiper-button-next {color: red}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример

```js
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
    loop: true,
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
    autoplay: {
        delay: 15000,
    },
    pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        type: 'bullets',
    },
    simulateTouch: false,
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;500&display=swap');

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #1F1F22;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
}

svg:hover {
    color: #D5A033;
}

.swiper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.swiper-text {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2222;
}

.swiper-text h1 {
    margin: 200px 0px 0px 175px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #D9B271;
    font-size: 48px;
    line-height: 58.51px;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.swiper-text p {
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 19.5px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 30px 0px 0px 175px;
}
.swiper-button-prev, 
.swiper-button-next {
    margin: 0px 80px;
}

.swiper-button-next::after, 
.swiper-button-prev::after {
    content: "";
}

.swiper-button-prev:hover, 
.swiper-button-next:hover,
.swiper-button-prev:focus, 
.swiper-button-next:focus{
    color: #D5A033!important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <title>Slider</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="swiper">
        <div class="swiper-text">
            <h1>Тренажерный<br>зал</h1>
            <p>В нашем клубе есть все для кроссфита</p>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://psv4.userapi.com/c235031/u524861121/docs/d34/ffdee0a224ec/strong-man-training-gym_3_1.png?extra=Pe_bJb7ma7Vmw2NHVcAvWvKvd3uIV5BoBrNrW5IU3vM5oOR5CY2FdPoDBoewzVaDqt5fjtQNuyBbUfI8W75dT0jy3lZiTZOvlnd4Z_hwUWXwd1UUX2Oo26EE0vbacd-Ow-06_noaFaNDic4NF8nFUQk">
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://psv4.userapi.com/c235031/u524861121/docs/d34/ffdee0a224ec/strong-man-training-gym_3_1.png?extra=Pe_bJb7ma7Vmw2NHVcAvWvKvd3uIV5BoBrNrW5IU3vM5oOR5CY2FdPoDBoewzVaDqt5fjtQNuyBbUfI8W75dT0jy3lZiTZOvlnd4Z_hwUWXwd1UUX2Oo26EE0vbacd-Ow-06_noaFaNDic4NF8nFUQk">
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://psv4.userapi.com/c235031/u524861121/docs/d34/ffdee0a224ec/strong-man-training-gym_3_1.png?extra=Pe_bJb7ma7Vmw2NHVcAvWvKvd3uIV5BoBrNrW5IU3vM5oOR5CY2FdPoDBoewzVaDqt5fjtQNuyBbUfI8W75dT0jy3lZiTZOvlnd4Z_hwUWXwd1UUX2Oo26EE0vbacd-Ow-06_noaFaNDic4NF8nFUQk">
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://psv4.userapi.com/c235031/u524861121/docs/d34/ffdee0a224ec/strong-man-training-gym_3_1.png?extra=Pe_bJb7ma7Vmw2NHVcAvWvKvd3uIV5BoBrNrW5IU3vM5oOR5CY2FdPoDBoewzVaDqt5fjtQNuyBbUfI8W75dT0jy3lZiTZOvlnd4Z_hwUWXwd1UUX2Oo26EE0vbacd-Ow-06_noaFaNDic4NF8nFUQk">
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <img src="https://psv4.userapi.com/c235031/u524861121/docs/d34/ffdee0a224ec/strong-man-training-gym_3_1.png?extra=Pe_bJb7ma7Vmw2NHVcAvWvKvd3uIV5BoBrNrW5IU3vM5oOR5CY2FdPoDBoewzVaDqt5fjtQNuyBbUfI8W75dT0jy3lZiTZOvlnd4Z_hwUWXwd1UUX2Oo26EE0vbacd-Ow-06_noaFaNDic4NF8nFUQk">
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev">
            <svg width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M15.3333 10.3467L9.66662 15.9973M9.66662 15.9973L15.3333 21.6478M9.66662 15.9973L22.6666 15.9973" stroke="white" stroke-width="2"/>
                <ellipse cx="16" cy="15.9971" rx="15" ry="14.9573" transform="rotate(-180 16 15.9971)" stroke="white" stroke-width="2"/>
            </svg>  
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-button-next">
            <svg width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M16.6666 21.6475L22.3333 15.997M22.3333 15.997L16.6666 10.3465M22.3333 15.997L9.33325 15.997" stroke="white" stroke-width="2"/>
                <ellipse cx="16" cy="15.9971" rx="15" ry="14.9573" stroke="white" stroke-width="2"/>
            </svg>  
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```